# phpMyAdmin not counting rows correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am not sure what to make of this. Seems like a bug, but it's so obvious that I must be doing something wrong. I am writing the queries phpMyAdmin's query box:

```
SELECT * FROM `useralert`
```

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (58157 total, Query took 0.0005 seconds.)

[image]

Now, I will add a condition, which must produce less rows than total number of rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `useralert` WHERE exchange='AVG'
```

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (63870 total, Query took 0.0004 seconds.)

[image]

---

See? Total number of rows in table is 58157, but querying with additional condition produces more rows? How can that even be possible? I have tripple checked I am not doing some stupid mistake (and that number of rows is not changing from outside).

Comment: I don't know the specifics of phpmyadmin, but some drivers are not required to estimate the exact number of rows (at least in JDBC) but to only give you an "idea" of it... whatever that is. Unless you actually retrieve the ALL the rows (you aren't) you won't really know how many there are for real.

Comment: Try SELECT COUNT(*) with and without the WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some databases only give an estimate of the number of rows returned, so the figure which phpMyAdmin gives shouldn't be trusted to be 100% accurate.

If you run the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useralert
```

and compare it with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useralert WHERE exchange='AVG'
```

The first query should be greater than or equal to the second one.

Answer (score 3):

For performance reasons, phpMyAdmin returns an approximate count. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=maxexactcount#cfg_MaxExactCount

How to obtain the exact count without changing the configuration : 
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq3-11